# Javascript: How to perform count on visible elements only?

Tags: javascript

I'm using jQuery to get a string from a search field and hide items that don't match. It loops through a list of divs and uses $(this).fadeOut(); to hide those elements.

This works very well, but I would like to add further searches within that search. I've added an extra search field, but of course it doesn't inherit the fade outs from the previous search and it starts again from the beginning.

**I need a way to specify to the searches to only search visible elements of the list.** This needs to work in reverse order as users might enter in the the second search field, then the first.

Here's a JSFiddle of my code illustrating the problem

[JSFiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/MUbPQ/)

And a code snippet of one search function

```
 $("#filter").keyup(function () { 
        var filter = $(this).val(),
        count = 0;
 $(".records2 div").each(function () {
 // If the list item does not contain the text phrase fade it out
        if ($(this).text().search(new RegExp(filter, "i")) < 0) {
            $(this).fadeOut();

            // Show the list item if the phrase matches and increase the count by 1
        } else {
            $(this).show();
            count++;
        }
  });
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
element.is(":visible")
```

To test if a given element is visible or not.

So in your case you'd just do:

```
if ($this).is(":visible")); {count++;}
```

Or you can add ":visible" to the end of your selectors to only pick the visible items:

```
$(".someselector div:visible").each(...);
```

Edit: I just checked the jquery documentation. You get better performance if you do:

```
$(".someselector div").filter(":visible").each(...);
```

This is because `:visible` isn't part of the CSS specification so jquery has to implement it manually.

Comment: if `( $(this).is(":visible") ) {count++}`

Comment: Excellent. The :visible on my selector seems to work well. Very simple and effective code!

Comment: Great, if you're happy with the answer - don't forget to tick the green tick to mark it as accepted.

Comment: One problem I've discovered with this approach is that you can't backspace as it will now only search visible elements. Any idea how I could address this?

Comment: Use the `:hidden` selector to sort those out separately in another loop.